# Xcode Switching View Controller after a Animation Loading Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, viewcontroller

I have followed a tutorial off of Geeky Lemon's Animation loading Screen's tutorial --->   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5nCSqppYHI   (link)

and I want to know how, after the animation loading screen, can I switch to my main ViewController that continues on to my Application?

Answer (score 0):

If you are following that tutorial you can simply push your desired view controller after animation is finished like below. Simply replace your delay3 method with the one here and also replace your view controller which you want to push.

Steps-

1. Import header file of your view controller in the current implementation file where you have written -(void)delay3 method like below.

   `#import "ViewController.h"`
2. Check following image and replace the ID in pushNewScreen method with the one in your storyboard.

[image]

```
- (void)delay3 {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];//you can change animation time here.
    [Loadingimageview setAlpha:1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // this method will call after 1 second you can change delay here.
    [self performSelector:@selector(pushNewScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
}

- (void)pushNewScreen {
    ViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardIdentifier"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It never worked? It does nothing after the delay 3 loads up

Comment: and what do you mean by replace you view controller you want to push? I'm sooooo sorry but thank you so much for the help so far!

Comment: Edited the answer. If that doesn't help you can send me the code.

Comment: For  ViewController *newView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardIdentifier"]; it was me to change the 'ViewController" to "UIViewController" or else it won't run, could you also send me a project link that you have done this coding too for I can see?